Meaning of permutation order in QR decomposition with pivoting
I used Matlab's qr function to calculate the qr decomposition of $A^H$, using:
[Q, R, P] = qr(A', 'vector').
This method uses pivoting and changes the order of the rows of $A$ (columns of $A^H$), in a way that A(P, :) = Q*R.
What does the order of the rows in the permutation say about rows of $A$? For example does the first row in the permutation have the highest or the lowest singular value or eigen-value?
In my case when I choose rows in the reverse order of $P$, I get better results : Why is that so?

OP : What does the order of the rows in the permutation say about rows of $A$ ?
Answer : Almost nothing
Details :
CASE 1 : When we use [Q, R] = qr(A) , we will get something which makes $A=QR$ which is the QR Decomposition , with no reordering.
CASE 2 : When we use [Q, R, P] = qr(A) , we are informing Matlab that we not only want the Decomposition , we also want the reordering where $abs(diag(R))$ is increasing.
It is no longer generally true that $A=QR$ , because we might get the reordered matrix.
We have to use $AP=QR$ , that is , we are reordering $A$ using the Permutation Matrix. Equivalently , we have $A=QRP^{-1}$
The $R$ is CASE 2 is the $R$ is CASE 1 reordered to ensure that $abs(diag(R))$ is increasing.
CASE 3 : When we use [Q, R, P] = qr(A, 'vector') , we are still informing Matlab that we not only want the Decomposition , we also want the reordering where $abs(diag(R))$ is increasing. We are additionally asking Matlab to give a vector with the reordering information.
Still it is no longer generally true that $A=QR$ , because we might get the reordered matrix.
We have to use $A(P, :)=QR$ , that is , we are reordering $A$ using the Permutation Vector.
The $R$ is CASE 3 is the same as the $R$ in CASE 2 , which is the $R$ is CASE 1 reordered to ensure that $abs(diag(R))$ is increasing.
In no way , we can generally talk about the rows of $A$ using $P$ Permutation Information.

When using QR on $A^H$, is the order of $P$ the reverse of the order of $P$ in the normal case?

(1) What is the $A^H$ ? (2) When we transpose the $A$ , then the $QR$ will also transpose. Naturally , we will now get the $P$ Permutation Matrix for the $Q$.
